# Pick up one element from array to variable using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript

I've got this code on dataLayer

```
{
    event: 'view_item',
    eventModel: {
        event_category: 'detail_view',
        event_label: '{"product_id":123456,"model":"XXX","brand":"YYY","price":100000"}'
    },
    gtm.uniqueEventId: 62
}
```

I would like to pick up only "product_id" value from event_label, and add it to GTM variables.
My question is, what function should I use to do this?

Thank you very much for help :)

I found also this js code:

```
gtag("event","view_item",{event_category:"details_view",event_label:JSON.stringify(Object(t["a"])({product_id:this.product.id,model:this.id.model,brand:this.id.brand,price:this.id.price})}),
```